# Static image and a folder of mp3's?

Tags: ffmpeg, batch-processing

I want to create a bunch of videos consisting of an single image which is shown throughout the whole video but each video has a different audio file. I can do it manually with various tools but the problem is that I have a lot of audio files and I can't optimize the frame rate (more on that later) and it takes a lot of time to do it that way but ffmpeg offers everything I need but the problem is that I don't know how to batch process everything.

The basic code:
`ffmpeg -i song-name.mp3 -loop 1 -i cover.jpg -r frame-rate -t song-length -acodec copy output.mp4`

What I want to achieve:
Let's say that I have a folder which consists of several audio files: song-name-1.mp3, song-name-2.mp3, ..., song-name-n.mp3 and cover.jpg.

I need a batch file which takes the name of every mp3 file in a folder (a FOR loop I suppose) and processes it with the same command:
`ffmpeg -i song-name.mp3 -loop 1 -i cover.jpg -r frame-rate -t song-length -acodec copy output.mp4`

So the image is always the same for every video. The song length can be taken with the tool [mp3info](http://ibiblio.org/mp3info/) and the corresponding command:
`mp3info.exe -p %S song-name.mp3`

Since I only have one image throughout the whole video, the optimal frame rate would be the inverse of the video length which is 1/length (where length is a variable in seconds which we get from mp3info).

So the final code should look something like this:
`ffmpeg -i song-name.mp3 -loop 1 -i cover.jpg -r 1/length -t length -acodec copy song-name.mp4`

Where "song-name" is a variable which changes for every iteration of the FOR loop (i.e. for every audio file in the folder) and length is a variable whose value we get with the command:
`mp3info.exe -p %S song-name.mp3`

I found examples of a FOR loop to fetch all file names of all mp3's in a specific folder but I do not know how to integrate mp3info. I hope that somebody can help me and I have some knowledge of the C programming language if that can be used in any way.

Comment: Instead of `-t <song duration>` simply use `-shortest`. Then you can ditch `mp3info.exe`.

Comment: I am afraid that this does not work correctly, I used a ~3 minute song and the result was a ~4 minute video. The song played correctly to the end but after that, there was of course only the picture without sound...

Comment: The ffmpeg command and the complete ffmpeg console output would be useful (and is basically a requirement when asking for help when using ffmpeg).

Comment: I see that you too noticed the strange behavior of the "-shortest"  option but I will keep your advice in mind and try to post the log files immediately when submitting a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the edited simplified version without the VBS math.

The reason %%S is used is that % is a special batch character used for %environment% variables and in forINdo loops and to get a single one in a forINdo command it has to be doubled.  Similarly `echo %%` will echo a single percent sign.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.mp3) do (
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('mp3info.exe -p %%S "%%a"') do (
ffmpeg -i "%%a" -loop 1 -i "cover.jpg" -r 1 -t %%b -acodec copy "%%~na.mp4"
)
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works like it should and you are right, the frame rate can't be less than 1 (it can but the player can't decode it). I thought this to be true because I read somewhere that for my purpose the best frame rate would be 1/length because if we multiply this by length we get 1 frame throughout the whole video but in practice this does not work that way so I specified the frame rate as a constant i.e. 1. Since there is no need for a vbs script then (if I understood you correctly) could you maybe post the simplified batch file which uses "-r 1"?

Comment: And also, could you maybe give me some advice which resources to use to learn batch and vbs scripting? (I want to learn why 'mp3info.exe -p **%%S** "%%a"' is correct and not 'mp3info.exe -p **%S** "%%a"')